# nodejs mysql not working with mariadb

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb

I have a node.js script that uses the mysql module and it runs fine on my local machine with mysql installed... When I try to run it on my server (with MariaDB installed) it fails to connect to the server (with every option I try).

When I tried to install the mariasql module it failed...

Can anyone suggest what to do? Or a module that supports both?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> it fails to connect to the server (with every option I try).

Please provide more information and submit a ticket on the GitHub issue page.